# Playing sound when receiving notification worked in dev but not in production

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, avfoundation, audio-player

i wanted to play a sound when i receive a specific notification no matter whether silent mode is turned on or not.

I get it working in dev mode with the AVFoundation framework. So in the AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method i initialize the `AVAudioSession`

```
NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&audioSessionError];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&audioSessionError];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

if(audioSessionError) {
    NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] audioSessionError: %@", audioSessionError);
}
```

I use the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler` method to check if the app is in background and the notification is the notification to play the sound.

```
if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {        
    NSDictionary *aps = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];

    if([[aps valueForKey:@"category"] isEqualToString:@"alarm"]) {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/alarm.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
        NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        NSError *audioPlayerError = nil;
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:&audioPlayerError];

        if(audioPlayerError) {
            NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] audioPlayerError: %@", audioPlayerError);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"[AppDelegate] audioPlayer play call");
            [self.audioPlayer play];
        }
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
} else {
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
}
```

The keys in the info.plist for the background mode `audio` and `remote-notification` are set.

Everything worked fine so i pushed the app without any changes to TestFlight. When the app now received a notification the alert is showing but the sound isn't playing when silent mode is turned on. So i tested it in dev again and there i got the same results. Notification is received and showing but sound isn't played.

I have no clue why it was working in dev before pushing it to TestFlight and after it it is whether working in production or in dev. The notification is received every time, only the sound not playing anymore.

Someone have any idea how this happened?

Comment: Is your `AVAudioSession` setup code actually called when you receive a notification?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman no, but its called when i start the app normally so that the `AVAudioSession` is started before the app goes to the background. So when the notification is received the `AVAudioPlayer` should be able to play, or am i wrong with my thoughts?

Comment: What if your app wasn't running when the notification came in? I don't know off hand if `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is called when a notification causes your app to launch. However, if it does cause your app to launch, I don't know if you can activate a `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` session from the background. Are you even in the background? Maybe with the option `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`? But does that still override the silent switch? I don't know. I don't know anything.

Comment: In my understanding `didFinishLaunchingWithOprions` gets only called when the app is launched. So its called when the user normally opened the app in foreground. When a notification is received and the app is in background, only `didReceiveRemoteNotification` gets called. When the app was force quitted by the user, nothing gets called and thats fine. I only want to override the silent switch when the app is in the background.

Comment: Is it possible you're not actually playing the sound? This documentation says that if your app is not running when the notification arrives, then `didReceiveNotification` will not be called as the information is passed via  the dictionary in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application

Comment: no, when i debug the code in dev i see that `didReceiveNotification` is called and `[self.audioPlayer play];` gets called, too. Only the sound seems not to play.

Comment: Maybe your `AVAudioSession` has been deactivated. Try calling `setActive` (checking errors) before playing?

Comment: Ty @RhythmicFistman with the try to activate the `AVAudioSession` in the delegate function i got an error message which helped me to find the solution with the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` option.

Comment: Cool - in hindsight this makes perfect sense. Why use a non mixable session category in an app that only occasionally makes sounds? Your dev app would have been restarted regularly, so the chances were good that the session had not been interrupted by some other external event. The longer running prod app on the other hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found a solution for my problem.

In the `AppDelegate.m` file at initializing the `AVAudioSession` I changed the line from

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&audioSessionError];
```

to

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers error:&audioSessionError];
```

With the new option `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers`, it works in dev and production.

Comment: Hello @chronisch, Can You Provide this App Delegate class for push notification for swift, I'm facing the same issue. I found Nothing till now. I have uploaded a question as well , But No response yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949854/not-getting-custom-sound-in-push-notification-in-production